# Able to get data from Mongo DB Atlas even after closing the connection?

Tags: pymongo

Using "with" in below way which should handle close connection

```
 custcmd = "mongodb+srv://{}:{}@{}/{}?retryWrites=true&w=majority".format(username,pwd,host,dbname)

 with MongoClient(custcmd.format(username,pwd)) as client:
    mydatabase = client[dbname] 
    mycollection=mydatabase[collectionname] 
    count = mycollection.count_documents({})
```

Tried below code outside "with" block and still got count. I suspect if it is working/not

```
count = mycollection.count_documents({}) 
print(count)
```

Am I using "with" in right way or is anything wrong? Could get data from db even after client.close() So how to use a connection?

Answer (score 0):

MongoClient has auto reopen, so closing the connection is fine, but if you make a subsequent call, the connection is reopened.

> close() ... Close all sockets in the connection pools and stop the monitor
> threads. If this instance is used again it will be automatically
> re-opened and the threads restarted unless auto encryption is enabled ([Reference](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.close))

Variables defined inside a with block work just the same as variables defined inside a for loop; they are available outside the block providing they have been initialised.

So everything is working as expected.

Key takeaway: **You don't need to worry about cleaning up the connection - pymongo handles all this for you. Just open your connection, do your stuff and that's it.**

If you really want to ensure you don't re-use an existing connection by accident, the best way is just to set any variables to None, e.g.

```
client = MongoClient(custcmd.format(username,pwd))
mydatabase = client[dbname] 
mycollection=mydatabase[collectionname] 
count = mycollection.count_documents({}) 

# All done, make sure we don't reconnect by accident!

client = mydatabase = mycollection = None
```